# Storing messages in a list after processing messages through kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have an application where I need to store the messages that are retrieved from kafka consumer. I  am storing all the records in a linkedlist while consuming the messages. I am retrieving that data structure through a getter in the kafkaListner class. I am not sure if this is a correct approach as the size of the linkedlist is 0. I found the size through debugging the code.

The Kafka listner class is as follows:

```
public class KafkaListeners {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaListeners.class);
private List<String> records = new LinkedList<>();


    @KafkaListener(topics = "kafka_topic", groupId = "kafkaGroupId")
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<byte[],byte[]> record) {
        setRecords(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(record.value()));
        LOGGER.info("Consuming Message: "+ Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(record.value()));
    }

    public List<String> getRecords() {
        return this.records;
    }

    private void setRecords(String record) {
        this.records.add(record);
    }
```

}

The kafka configruation is as follows:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfigruation {

private  String kafkaTopics;
private  String kafkaHosts;
private  String kafkaGroupId;
private  String AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG_VALUE = "earliest";

//ignore these errors
public KafkaConfigruation(String kafkaHosts, String KafkaTopics, String kafkaGroupId) {
    this.kafkaHosts = kafkaHosts;
    this.kafkaTopics = KafkaTopics;
    this.kafkaGroupId = kafkaGroupId;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<byte[],byte[]> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.kafkaHosts);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
    

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<byte[],byte[]> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<byte[],byte[]> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

}

The utility class where I am getting the messages is as follows:

```
 public void getRecords(String consumer, String environment, String schemaDefinition,
                           String topicList)throws IOException{
        String kafkahost = getKafkaHosts(StringUtils.upperCase(environment));
        kafkaConfigruation = new KafkaConfigruation(kafkahost,topicList,consumer);

        List<String> response = kafkaListeners.getRecords();
     
        
    }
```

Comment: When are you actually calling `getRecords()`? Before the Listener actually runs? Also, Spring should load your configuartion classes on its own, so its unclear what `new KafkaConfigruation` is for.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, how can I call getRecords() after listener runs ?

Comment: Well, you could use an http endpoint that you can call whenever you want to get data. My point is that you cannot just run the Spring main method, and immediately expect there to be data. Nor, can you set a breakpoint and pause the listener execution and expect data, either.

Comment: Note: You can also just use a [batch listener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#batch-listeners) to directly get a list

Comment: @OneCricketeer, is there any other way? Batch listner is not working with my data type

Comment: What do you mean? `List<byte[]>` should work fine since you only care about the value, or better (as documented) `List<Message>`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, can you explain through code snippet ? I am newbie in kafka

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to achieve here; also using a non-synchronized list in a multi-threaded environment is not safe. Perhaps start over by explaining your use case and exactly what you need to do.

Comment: The documentation gives exactly the code needed to consume lists with batch listeners, but it obviously doesn't help solve your problem of if/when you actually checking what you've consumed. Plus, if you really want to query data you've gotten from Kafka, you might also want to read about the Interactive Queries service feature from Spring